# What is Mgt_Base module?

Tags: module, xml, log

I was hunting for the cause of some SimpleXMLElement errors in my log when I found out the culprit was some module in `app/etc/modules` called Mgt_Base. The errors showed up when I accessed the adminpanel

I'm trying to figure out whether I can just disable the module to stop the log errors or whether it's essential. Unfortunately I'm new to Magento so I'm having a hard time trying to find out exactly what this module does.

Does anyone know what this Mgt_Base module is supposed to do or how I can find out that information?

Answer (score 0):

Mgt_Base is not default magento module.May this is third party extension.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm having an awfully hard time searching online for what it even does.